# string,int and float validation in C++

Tags: c++, validation, input

BIG EDIT: I added in and it now detects string inputs :)!

```
if (false == isdigit(grade[0])
```

edit: The problem: can not determine if I put in a string instead of a float or int.

I've been looking all through this website and there's many posting about checking string input. Here is my take on trying to combine everything I learned, and as you can see, It's not doing what I want it to do.

Such inputs and what happens:

user input: "1.2" : can tell it's a float

user input: "1" : can tell it's a int

user input: "a": ERROR : think's it's a float. This is the problem. If I enter in 'a' I need the program to recognize that a string was inputted and this calling in certain functions.

Some guidance would be much appreciated:

```
#include "assessGrade.h"


int main(void)
{

int finalGrade = 0;
int gradeHolder = 0;
int numberGrade[5] = { 0,0,0,0,0 };
double doubleGrade = 0;

//my beloved bool's
bool floatGrade = false;
bool intGrade = false;
bool stringGrade = false;

//======================================//
// Getting the input from user          //
// Also check for stringfloat/int type  //
//======================================//
std::string grade;
std::getline(std::cin, grade);
std::stringstream stream(grade);


if (false == isdigit(grade[0]))
{
    //it's not a digit
    cout << "STRING: " << grade << endl;
    stringGrade = true;
}

else if(!(stream >> gradeHolder) || grade.find('.') != std::string::npos)
{
    //its a float!
    cout << "FLOAT: " << grade << endl;
    floatGrade = true;
}
else
{
    //it's a int!
    cout << "INTEGER: " << grade << endl;
    intGrade = true;
}


//======================================//
// Parsing the input                    //
//======================================//
if (intGrade == true)
{
    //do int stuff here
}


else if (floatGrade == true)
{
    //do float stuff here
    //doubleGrade = grade;
}


else
{
    //do string stuff here
}
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Describe your problem more concisely. What is your problem specifically?

Comment: @cad I put in an edit, I hope that help's but because I'm typing this now my program isn't able to determine if I put in a string instead of a float.

Comment: Your first test doesn't make sense. If the first char in the input is a digit, why are you classifying it as a string?

Comment: Beware of the user inputting empty lines. In that case, there is no first character, but you assume there is.

Comment: @mat My mistake, I've fixed that up to be more clear. My idea was that it will just test the first char of the user input, and if the test proves that it is not a digit, it would have to be a string thus prompting the corresponding function.

Comment: @Robolisk I'm kind of confused about `if (isdigit(grade[0])){//it's not a digit` isn't that misleading?

Comment: @PeterT I added in an edit, does that make more sense?

Answer (score 0):

It's far from easy to determine exactly what a "float value" would be. Is `+1.0E-02` a float variable? It's got a letter in it!

You almost got the decent solution. Use `std::stringstream` to see if you can extract an integer or float value. You will need to `.clear()` it, if the first attempt fails.

Comment: I'm still fairly new to the C++ environment, but I'll do some digging to see what I can do with that. Thank you for the guidance! I'll get back to you on any discoveries.